# php public function is not working outside of the class

Tags: php, class, oop, php-5.6, public-method

I have created a simple class, variable, and public function.  When I try to initiate an object and call the public function from the class outside of the class, I get no output that I can see.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("error_reporting", 1);

  class Game {
    var name;

    public function show_game() {
      echo $this->name;
    }
  }

  $game = new Game;
  $game->name = "testing game";

  $game->show_game();
?>
```

From what I understand, the function should echo out *testing game*. But I am not seeing any output when I load up the page.

Comment: *"But I am not seeing any output when I load up the page."* - Well, you should with your error reporting set. If that doesn't throw you a parse error, then I have my own views as to what's "not" going on. I'll let you take it up with the answers below.

Comment: You guys down there paying attention up here? Read the question again; completely. Specifically ***"I get no output"***. Edit: I guess not.

Comment: *"I get no output that I can see."* - I don't believe you `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("error_reporting", 1);`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I wonder how long it will take to find the next syntax error with no output.  I tried running it in the console, and whaddaya know?  It didn't complain!  Then I looked up error reporting, LOL. Take careful aim at your foot... (the OP's foot, that is)

Comment: @Fred-ii- what are you going on about??  I didn't get an output or an error, and just now I found out the company is having wifi difficulties so I suspect that some of my issue may have been caused by my file not actually uploading to the server.

Comment: What he's going on about is that you shot yourself in the foot with `ini_set("error_reporting", 1);`  You just told PHP to NOT tell you what's wrong.

Comment: And the answers below, while accurate, didn't address how to help you learn how to catch your own mistake.  Frankly, I wouldn't have seen it without his comment, because I don't change the error level in my scripts, so I just glossed over it, although I wondered why you added the second one.  But then again, check my rep against theirs...

Comment: Ok excellent, I have been confused about setting error reporting for a while.  What would be the way to tell php to show errors for the specific page I am using?

Comment: well, since I don't do that in my scripts, what I would try would be `ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);` for when I'm developing.  Actually, that's not true.  I just wouldn't do it.  Set it in php.ini according to whether you're in a development or production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var name;
```

Is not valid syntax, change to:

```
var $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have simply forgotten the `$` in your PHP variable. `var name` should be `var $name`:

```
<?php
  class Game {
    var $name;
    public function show_game() {
      echo $this->name; // Returns "testing game"
    }
  }
  $game = new Game;
  $game->name = "testing game";
  $game->show_game();
?>
```

Hope this helps! :)